# jQuery callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have a function - `vertToggle()` - that toggles an element to slide up and down off the screen. I want to create a chain of events that slides the element off screen, changes the content within it, then slides it back up. However they need to be fired one after the other, not at the same time so they need to be setup as callbacks to one another.

The current, non-working, setup is:

```
vertToggle( '-' );
$(".content").hide()
$("#"+load).show();
vertToggle( '+' );
```

However I don't have my head around the necessary callback function syntax to make these trigger correctly, ie perform `vertToggle()`, when complete do the `hide/show` inbetween, then when these are done perform the second `vertToggle()`.

Thanks for any pointers.

EDIT: as requested this is the vertToggle function, not sure if it's relevant.. $overlay is the element that is being animated:

```
function vertToggle( offset ) {
    var height = $overlay.outerHeight();
    var props = {};
    var distance = ( offset == '-' ) ? height : 0 ;
    props["bottom"] = offset+distance+'px';

    if( !Modernizr.csstransitions ) {
        $overlay.animate(props, 750);
        $overlay.toggleClass("open");
    }
    else {
        $overlay.css(props);
        $overlay.toggleClass("open");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `vertToggle()`?

Comment: Sorry - that's the function I've created to take care of the toggling

Comment: Ok, then we need to see that functions code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.slideToggle()`, you can add a function as a callback.

```
$("something").click(function(){
 $("somethingelse").slideToggle(function(){
   CallbackFunction()
 })
});
```

Does that help?

Comment: I haven't used slideToggle due to the ugly way it animates the content within the element, I just want the entire panel to slide up or down.

Comment: slideToggle just alters the height as far as I can tell. The `hide("slow")` and `show("slow")` animate the content in an ugly way